# How to read multiple images from disk and display them dynamicaly as node icons in R

Tags: r

I am able to achieve the same with qgraph with the below code. however i would like to do the same using igraph and 
display the images as node icons dynamically using igraph so that i can have better control of each vertex.

```
require(qgraph)
img<-c    ("imagepath/1.jpg","imagepath/2.jpg","imagepath/3.jpg","imagepath/4.jpg","imagepath/5.jpg","imagepath/6.jpg" )
demo_adj <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,'B','X','Y','A'),to=c('A','B','A','Y','1','Y'))
qgraph(demo_adj,images=img)
```

I am guessing i should
be able to color each edges based on certain condition. Any suggestion on the above shall be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vertex.shape="raster` option of `plot.igraph` function.

```
library(jpeg)
library(igraph)
## here you should give your real path
ll <- list.files(PATH_TO_IMAGES,pattern='.*jpg',full.names=TRUE)
rasters <- lapply(ll,readJPEG)
## create the graph
gg <- graph.data.frame(demo_adj)
## set raster attribute
V(gg)$raster <- rasters[1:length(V(gg))]
plot(gg, layout=layout.star, vertex.shape="raster",
     vertex.label=V(gg)$name, margin=.2,
     vertex.size=50, vertex.size2=50,
     vertex.label.dist=2, vertex.label.degree=0)
```

[image]

**edit**

To add pictures names as vertex labels , you can do something like:

```
ll.names <-  list.files(PATH_TO_IMAGES,pattern='.*jpg')
ll.names <- gsub('[.].*','',ll.names)
V(gg)$name <- ll.names[1:length(V(gg))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, It is working really very well. Will you please enhnance me this >> with one more field in the demo_adj with image name. and that image should represent corresponding to that node. So that the sequence of read image doesn't bother of its related node

Comment: thanks for all the replies, and this is really very helpful to me,